# STACK: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"'

Tags: jestjs

running jest gives the following error 
Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from /Users/****/****/somefile.js
ERROR: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (3:0)
STACK: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (3:0)

i have tried babel-jest also it was not working. what could be the possible issue here, why the import, export is not being identified here???

/* content of somefile.js */
somefile.js

```
export * from './file-1';
export * from './file-2';
```

/* babelrc conf */

```
"test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": [
                "last 2 versions",
                "edge >= 12",
                "explorer >= 10"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "react",
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "import",
          {
            "libraryName": "antd",
            "style": true
          }
        ],
        "lodash",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "recharts",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-runtime"
      ]
    }
```

/* jest config */

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '.*_spec\\.(js|jsx)$',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    "!<rootDir>/node_modules/**"
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/config/jest/SetupStorageMock.js'
  ],
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/node_modules/some-jest/src/SetupReactEnzyme.js',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json'],
  moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/prism-jest/src/styleMock.js',
    '^actions\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/actions/$1',
    '^components\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^containers\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/containers/$1',
    '^globals\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/globals/$1',
    '^hocs\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/hocs/$1',
    '^i18n\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/i18n/$1',
    '^utils\\/([^\\.]*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils/$1'
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'json-summary'],
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/prism-jest/src/CoverageThreshold.js',
      { coverageThresholdFile: './config/jest/coverageThreshold.json' }
    ]
  ],
  bail: true
};
```